# Op-Amp - Sharing Non-Inverting Inputs in a two stage amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier

I've mocked up a simple circuit using a TL064A to reduce the single level of a single ended input audio source.

I'm using two stages per channel, and both stages on each channel are sharing a connection to AGND. Is there anything inherently wrong with this? I understand that the Op-Amp will force the inputs to the same voltage, and I'm concerned this may lead to interference.

Here's my schematic:

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Please put the actual values on the circuit because saying please ignore etc. is not useful. Please also justify why you are using R44 and R47 instead of shorts. Also, if you are wanting to reduce gain why use two stages per channel?

Comment: *to reduce the gain of a given single ended input audio source* Not clear what you mean, an audio source does not have "gain", an amplifier can have gain. Maybe you mean: "decrease the signal level", then I'd just use a resistor divider, no opamp needed. Your circuit might work as 2 buffers, that's not very clear. Anyway, there's no "gain reduction" or "signal attenuation" going on so to me it is unclear why this circuit exists.

Comment: @Andyaka - Updated with actual values. I can't justify R44 and R47 -- I'm not an EE, so I simply thought that if the inverting inputs need a resistor, the non-inverting would too. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie - I've updated my OP with the actual resistor values, which should decrease the input signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TL064 op amp has a JFET input and the bias current is very low. R44 and R47 serve no purpose. The only reason for these resistors is to reduce errors caused by the input bias currents. However, the small input bias current going through these resistors will produce an offset voltage which is much less than the input offset voltage of the op amps. The resistors might be useful if the op amp had bipolar transistor inputs but this is not the case. The only effect of the resistors will be to add some noise in the circuit.

BTW, if the resistors were used to reduce input bias current error, this technique relies on the input bias currents on the - and + inputs to be somewhat matching. This tends to be the case for bipolar input op amps. However, using the same resistor for two op amps means the offset voltage created by one op amp input currents will be an error for the other op amp. This is the main reason to not connect the + inputs from two op amps together to one compensating resistor.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation! To summarize, I'm best off just directly connecting the non-inverting inputs to the analog ground, as the resistors will only add noise, then?

Answer (score 1):

This should not be a problem.  I'd recommend a resistor for each amp on the noninverting input, and the resistor value should be 50K, and not 100K, to reduce bias voltage (though the actual ideal value will depend on the values of the resistors on the inverting input and the feedback resistors.

In any case, so long as you're reducing the gain, and not increasing it, small biases won't be a problem for you anyway.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the OP with the actual values of Rf (Ri was not changed). How would I go about calculating the ideal values for the resistors on the non-inverting inputs?

Comment: It's the value of the parallel combination of the resistor on the inverting terminal and the feedback resistor.